# Can you put one demisemiquaver rest inside a group of 4 demisemiquavers?

Tags: notation, rhythm, engraving, beaming, rests

I did a picture with 2 examples so you guys can see what I mean. Please can you tell me if blue or red is better?

[image: A rhythm in 3/8 with different beaming. The first (red) example has a rest under a partially broken beam. The second (blue) breaks the beam completely at the rest.]

Comment: Why not use 3/4 time, double the bpm, and not have to use such 'short' notes? Or use staccato marks instead?

Comment: Short reply to @Tim , which I recall reading from another answer recently, which was a good reminder to me: rest is rhythm, staccato is articulation; best not conflate the two.

Comment: It might look better with the 3 lines going all the way across. I don't like the blue option at all; I think the red option is clearer to read.

Comment: Even better: combine the two 32nd note rests in the first beat into one 16th rest.

Comment: What instrument is this for?

Comment: Boosey and Hawkes is the type of publisher that will beam across that inner 32nd rest (I've seen them beam across inner 16th rests a ton). Maybe they're on the right track.

Comment: @Neal - true, but in this example, it's hardly going to make any difference - except to read.

Comment: @phoog - probably a theory question, thus no particular.

Comment: @Tim but it makes a difference, for example if it is a percussion part for an instrument that isn't typically damped, in which case it would be far better (much easier to read) to write the rhythm out without rests.

Comment: @phoog - with snare, kick, tom, et al, I wouldn't be writing rests anyway. They come as part of the instrument ! Cymbal would need rests marked, to get it played choked.

Comment: @Tim that's precisely my point.

Comment: @tim rests don't really imply a choked cymbal.

Comment: @AndrewGallasch - so how does one write for it?

Comment: @Tim by writing the word choke, some sources say use an apostrophe, + or other articulation marking to indicate choke, but you might want to specify your method at the top of the drum part as there doesn't seem to be clear consensus.

Comment: @AndrewGallasch - rather like so much drum music! So staccato marks would suffice.

Answer (score 8):

The beam keeps  the 4 notes/or rest together = 1 beat. This assembling makes it immediately plausible for reading. Thus the red version is much better and more usual.

Comment: With the note that engraving rules will probably add a little more height to the beam or move the rests lower, so that the rests fit comfortably below where the beams "would have been," allowing the eye to connect them.

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide a visual example of what you're seeing in comments and Albrecht's answer:

[image]

Having the three beams encompass the entire beat (and thus beaming over the rest itself) makes especially clear to the reader that this is all a single metrical unit. Otherwise, the reader may, however temporarily, question whether the lone thirty-second note at the end is a part of a new beat.

Answer (score 0):

If it's percussion, you might prefer

[image: separately]

or

[image: joined.]